# Data missing when read from text file with line breaks in Android

Tags: android, android-file

I have three strings which write in to list.txt file with this code

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String filename=filepath+"/" + FOLDER +  "/" + "list.txt"   ;   
FileOutputStream fop = null;
File file = null;

try {
    file =new File(filename);
    fop=new FileOutputStream(file,true);
    // if file doesn't exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    filecontent=filecontent+ System.getProperty ("line.separator");
    // get the content in bytes
    byte[] contentInBytes = filecontent.getBytes();

    fop.write(contentInBytes);
    fop.flush();
    fop.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The file output detail is

```
abc.mp3
cde.mp3
edf.mp3
```

Now, I want to read the detail in `list.txt`. I used below code but the output only has

```
cde.mp3
edf.mp3
```

What is happen with my code? I don't know why data `abc.mp3` disappear.

```
ArrayList<String> data;
try {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        String filename=filepath+"/" + FOLDER +  "/" + "list.txt"   ;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String audio_name;
        audio_name = in.readLine();
        data = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((audio_name = in.readLine()) != null) {                  
            data.add(audio_name);
        }
        in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File Read Error");
}
for (int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
    {
      Log.d("D",String.valueOf(data.get(i)));
    }
```

Comment: `if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();`.Remove that. OutputStream will create the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first instance of `audio_name = in.readLine()` would read the first line `abc.mp3` but the input is not used.  Thus first line read by your `while` loop and stored in `data` would be `cde.mp3`.  You should remove the first instance of `audio_name = in.readLine()`.

Comment: Redundant? It consumes the first file name.

Comment: Yes that is the reason of the missing line.

Answer (score 1):

```
audio_name = in.readLine();
data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You read your first line into your audio_name variable, but you never add it to the list, so that's why it's "missing".